# MySQL query - better performance with more specificity on JOIN?

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I'm writing a MySQL query and I have a doubt: which of these codes (below) are faster? I think if I'm more specific in "left join" (second code) it should be faster. Is this approach correct?

```
SELECT  m.*, p.nome AS nomeprocedimento
FROM medicos AS m
    LEFT JOIN medicoprocedimento AS mp ON m.id = mp.medicoid
    LEFT JOIN procedimentos AS p ON mp.procedimentoid = p.id
WHERE m.id = 123
```

OR

```
SELECT  m.*, p.nome AS nomeprocedimento
FROM medicos AS m
    LEFT JOIN medicoprocedimento AS mp ON m.id = mp.medicoid AND mp.medicoid = 123
    LEFT JOIN procedimentos AS p ON mp.procedimentoid = p.id
WHERE m.id = 123
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Do you really need `LEFT`?  Are you expecting `p.nome` to be NULL in some cases?

Comment: These return 2 different functions of input, unless certain constraints hold, so arguing about which is faster is moot. [mre] Plus this shows no research. [ask] [help] Also "faster" depends on circumstances you don't give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field is indexed, it *usually* doesn't make much difference, because the query optimizer will see that you're looking for a single value from the `medicoprocedimento.medicoid` (or `medicos.id`) column. So, it will *usually* do an index seek/scan on this value **before it does the join** even if you only have the filter in the `where` clause and not directly in the `join`.

That said, you should always check your execution plans to verify that this optimization is being done before you settle on your choice. There's no substitute for seeing *what actually happens when you run the query*.

Comment: I enjoyed your considerations. Thank you very much! (sorry my poor english)

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXPLAIN to know which one is faster, but for your example should be the same.

Comment: I tried EXPLAIN (command) but I got the same answer. So, I've put this question to see some opinions.

Comment: If the explain command show the same result, then it should be the same.

Comment: Okay, but today I don't have many rows. I was thinking in a scenario with a large number of rows if it could have a different performance.

Comment: As long as the index used in the EXPLAIN command is the same, the performance will be the same. Feel free to try it with a large data set, I am pleased to learn if I am wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

adding what Slimns say your query can be simplify with

```
SELECT  m.*, p.nome AS nomeprocedimento
FROM medicos AS m
    INNER JOIN medicoprocedimento AS mp 
            ON m.id = mp.medicoid 
           AND m.id = 123
    LEFT JOIN procedimentos AS p ON mp.procedimentoid = p.id
```

and I bet the second `LEFT JOIN` also can be replaced by `INNER JOIN`

Comment: This query is not equal to the one in the question.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Are you sure?. `LEFT JOIN ON id` with `WHERE id = something` is same as `INNER JOIN on id = something`

Comment: Inner join would return no rows if there is no medicoprocedimento. Left join would return medicos even in this case.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek you are right, I tought the `Where` was `mp.medicoid`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I have a scenario where I can have some id in medicos that is not present in medicoprocedimento, so this does not fit my needs.